# Which is beginner friendly Linq to sql or Entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, ado.net

I have just started learning asp .net web forms, I do have knowledge of web development as have done few todolist and blog type pet projects with php and have created simple CRUD in CodeIgniter. I was wondering what to learn and what will be easy for a beginner to grasp Linq to SQL or entity framework ?
I wanted to learn faster and create something that I have in my mind as STARTUP project. I only have 1 month to learn Database layer and only 15 days to at-least master basic CRUD of .net rest one moth will be spent on learning asp's stuff and AJAX.
Few are suggesting me to first learn ADO.net ?
**Maybe I'm completely messed about these technologies because of my lack of knowledge in .net field.**

Comment: LINQ to SQL is dead. Use Entity Framework or nHibernate.

Comment: Id also advise you use MVC rather than web forms.  For reasons of testability and extensibility.

Comment: MVC is preferred.  If you must use Asp.Net webforms, research the MVP pattern.   EntityFramework is probably where you want to spend your time, not LinqToSql.  As stated, LinqToSql has fallen out of favor.

Comment: @DavidL I am not asking vs ,I am asking which is easier to learn for beginner.

Comment: @MarkWalsh
I have planned only to learn web forms , I would prefer to use PHP when MVC is required :) BTW i am not saying asp.net MVC is not good or anything like that it's just I don't want to learn it unless I am getting paid to do so.
**Note:- I am a student.**

Comment: @Shashi I've removed my duplicate objection and provided an answer that I hope you'll find useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's worth noting that there are three approaches that can be taken with Entity Framework:

- Model First
- Code First
- Database First

While I may be incorrect in this assumption, my experience has been that Model First has lost quite a bit of popularity, thus boiling down to just two options.  That said, the fact that there is more than one way to "skin the Entity Framework Cat" means that you are adding to its inherent complexity.

Second of all, Entity Framework is incredibly powerful.  It is a true ORM with incredibly flexibility and power...IF you know how to use it.

Which is more difficult to learn?  Probably Entity Framework.  That said, you're not in the business of learning what is easier, you're in the business of learning solutions for the given problem.  If you're going to pick up an ORM, I'd rather learn the option that is considered the mainstay of the category.

If you want something that is less complex in terms of features, but requires more hands-on sql, consider learning Dapper.  It is quite impressive...as a Micro ORM.

And finally, there is very little reason for you NOT to learn .NET MVC over Webforms.  That's where the work is going.  Prioritize learning the technologies that will advance your career.  You'll be grateful that you put in the effort in the long run.